# Modx revo check on member group returns an array, how do I convert it to a string for use in a query?

Tags: php, arrays, modx

I'm developing a custom component in modx, the client has asked that it be searched by resource group id. I've got snippet pulling in the resource group ID, by using the following code:

```
// Check if user is logged in and get user group 
$user = (!empty($userId)) ? $modx->getObject('modUser', $userId) : $modx->user;

if (is_object($user)) {
    /*
    * modUser Groups
    */
    $group = print_r($user->getUserGroups(), true);
    $modx->toPlaceHolder('user.groups', $group);

}
```

However $group returns as an array, so I can't use it in the query:

```
Array ( [0] => 8 )
```

I've tried calling it like this: return $group[0];

But that just dumps the first letter 'A'

Basically I just want to place the value in the Array into a variable and then use it in my search query:

```
$query->where(array('accNumber:LIKE' => "%$accNo%"));
$query->andCondition(array('accName:LIKE' => "%$accName%"));
$query->andCondition(array('saleProperty:LIKE' => "%$saleProperty%"));
$query->andCondition(array('clientNumber' => "$group"));
```

Am I right in thinking that I'll need to convert the contents of the array into a string before I can use them? Sorry if the question is noobish, but I'm a noob!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested already, remove the `print_r()` so $groups will contain an array.

```
$group = $user->getUserGroups();
```

Then adjust your final `andCondition()` as follows (`:IN` is expecting an array):

```
$query->where(array('accNumber:LIKE' => "%$accNo%"));
$query->andCondition(array('accName:LIKE' => "%$accName%"));
$query->andCondition(array('saleProperty:LIKE' => "%$saleProperty%"));
$query->andCondition(array('clientNumber:IN' => $group));
```

http://rtfm.modx.com/display/xPDO20/xPDOQuery.where

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `print_r` -> `$group = $user->getUserGroups()` , and try again  `return $group[0];`

Answer (score 0):

yes - you will have to convert it, but it's returning an array as any given user can belong to more than one group, you might plan ahead for that one in case your client decides to change how they manage users.